# Footnotes and logo in Rmarkdown generated PDF

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdf-generation

I am trying to integrate footnotes AND a logo on the frontpage of a Rmarkdown generated PDF.

I try this:

```
---
title             : "My report"
date              : November 4th, 2022
author:  "Author 1[^note1]"
documentclass     : report
keep_tex          : true
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{titling}
- \pretitle{\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{logo.png}\LARGE\\}
- \posttitle{\end{center}}
output            : pdf_document
---

[^note1]: Writing, Research, Editing
```

Inspired by this procedure to integrate the logo:
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-logo.html

And this for the footnotes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62514739/12398676

However, I am getting this error:

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.69 ...or 1\footnote{Writing, Research, Editing}}

Error: LaTeX failed to compile logo_footnote.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See logo_footnote.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Anyone has an idea of what is going wrong?

EDIT: the solution provided by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
... is one step closer to the solution but not quite there.
I now have a logo and author name, but the author name is overlayed with the date
[image: Overlay author date]

EDIT2: In the solution provided by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I get a similar display problem even without a logo

```
---
title             : "My report"
date              : November 4th, 2022
documentclass     : report
keep_tex          : true
header-includes:
- \AtBeginDocument{\author{Author 1\protect\footnote{Writing, Research, Editing}}}
output            : 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---
test
```

[image: Author date bug]

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the problem like this:

```
---
title             : "My report"
date              : November 4th, 2022
documentclass     : report
keep_tex          : true
header-includes: 
- \AtBeginDocument{\author{Author 1\protect\footnote{Writing, Research, Editing}}}
- \usepackage{titling}
- \pretitle{\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=2in,height=2in]{example-image-duck}\LARGE\par}
- \posttitle{\end{center}}
output            : 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---

test
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, that's already good, but I'm not quite there as now the author name is not displayed properly (overlayed with the date)
https://file.io/yqI4t84uJwJo

Comment: @raphael_ldl Can you please add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: Done, see above

Comment: @raphael_ldl Can't reproduce. Is your rmarkdown, pandoc and tex distribution up to date?

Comment: I just reinstalled rmarkdown, pandoc and tinytex. Still same problem.
Note that we are using different logos - my R is not finding the example-image-duck that you are using. 
It seems like on your example, there is a milder version of the same problem (see how the "p" from "report" touches the "4" from "November 4th").
I tried adding a newline before the date
- \predate{\newline}
But this doesn't work
(! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.)

Comment: @raphael_ldl example-image-duck should be available on all systems on which the latex duckuments package is installed. If you don't have it, you can also use `example-image-a` from the `mwe` package. The letters touching is due to to font size changes without starting a new paragraph afterwards.

Comment: Okay, thanks. However, I still don't know how to work around my problem. I get the same without a logo (see new picture above).
For now, I will insert the logo manually into the pdf, but it might be interesting to solve this issue